# what is (function(){}()) in object when i make a function

Tags: javascript

if I remove the ";" after let self = this; then it does not work

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'john',
  getInfo: function() {
    let self = this;
    (function() {
      console.log(self.name)
    }())

  }
}
obj.getInfo();
```

Comment: Seems a bit pointless, why not just use `console.log(this.name)` as the only line of the `getInfo` function?

Comment: Seems like it is a function that is not assigned to anything but automatically executes itself - useless js

Comment: Maybe it has educational purposes(scopes of `this` and `self`)

Comment: Look up IIFE. It has its use cases, this does not seem like a valid one.

Comment: _“If I remove the `;` after `let self = this;` then it does not work”_ — Why do you expect it to work? See [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/4642212).

Comment: Well replace `self.name` in the `console.log` with some literal like `"hello"` and you will see the real error here: `'this' is not a function`. Semicolon is important in situations like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `this` and `;`, and the code below makes it much simpler without using `this`, nor `;`:

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'john',
  getInfo: () => console.log(obj.name) 
}
obj.getInfo();
```